# Advanced custom fields if else statement

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the plugin Advanced Custom Fields. The following example code is given on the acf website for if statements.

```
<?php

if(get_field('field_name'))
{
    echo '<p>' . get_field('field_name') . '</p>';
}

?>
```

I have tried adding an else statement like so:

```
<?php
if(get_field('main_title'))
{
    echo '<h1>' . get_field('main_title') . '</h1>';
}
else 
{
    echo '<h1>' . the_title() . '</h1>' ;
}
?>
```

The snippet works perfectly if I enter data into the `main_title` field in WP Admin, but if it's blank, the default page title is outside the `<h1>` tags.

Thank you for your patience. I'm a bit of a PHP noob!

Comment: Have you read [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) in Codex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using version of template tag that echoes result immediately and so unsuitable to concatenate in string. You should be using [`get_the_title()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_title/) for this purpose,